# generate a cpp exe using json in vscode

Tags: c++, json, g++, visual-studio-code

I use this json file to generate a cpp exe in vs code, but it is unpleasant...After compiling a source file named 001.cpp, it generated a cpp exe named 001.cpp.exe. What should I do to generate a cpp exe named 001.exe?
Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "args": ["-g","${file}","-o","${file}.exe"],   
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "cpp",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `${file}` by `${fileDirname}/${fileBasename}` ?

Comment: yep, I tried  and it didn't work